# python generating netaddr.core.NotRegisteredError invalid syntax exception

Tags: python

I am trying to get a piece of software called [Probemon](https://gitlab.com/datrv4/probemon)
working and have come up with an error when I try to run it.

```
root@root:~/probemon/src$ python3 ./probemon.py -h
  File "./probemon.py", line 69
    except netaddr.core.NotRegisteredError, e:
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am not sure what it is trying to indicate here...

Prior to this I have run these commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/drkjam/netaddr
cd netaddr
sudo python setup.py install
cd
git clone https://github.com/secdev/scapy.git
cd scapy
sudo python setup.py install
```

to ensure netaddr and scapy dependencies are installed.

I have python 2 and python3 installed as this was default on the raspberrypi distro and I note from the probemon webpage, you

> This is still using python2   ️. This is easily converted to
> python3 script with 2to3 though

but I'm not sure where this needs to change.  I have found the first line of probemon.py as

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
```

and changed it to

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

although I am not sure whether this is what this means.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Thanks

---

Edit to show response to running with python2:

```
root@root:~/probemon/src$ python2 ./probemon.py -h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./probemon.py", line 11, in <module>
    import netaddr
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netaddr-0.8.0-py2.7.egg/netaddr/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from netaddr.core import (AddrConversionError, AddrFormatError,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netaddr-0.8.0-py2.7.egg/netaddr/core.py", line 11, in <module>
    from netaddr.compat import _callable, _iter_dict_keys
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netaddr-0.8.0-py2.7.egg/netaddr/compat.py", line 93, in <module>
    import importlib_resources as _importlib_resources
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/importlib_resources-3.0.0-py2.7.egg/importlib_resources/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ._common import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/importlib_resources-3.0.0-py2.7.egg/importlib_resources/_common.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ._compat import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/importlib_resources-3.0.0-py2.7.egg/importlib_resources/_compat.py", line 42, in <module>
    from zipp import Path as ZipPath  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zipp-3.1.0-py2.7.egg/zipp.py", line 217
    def open(self, mode='r', *args, pwd=None, **kwargs):
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: try to run it with python2 ./probemon.py  instead. This script is to be ran with python2 (converting it in python3 is "easy" but still requires you to run a script according to the author's message).

Answer (score 1):

The script you have is compatible only with python2.

You can choose one of the following solutions:

- run it using  `python2 ./probemon.py` instead (if python2 is installed on your machine)
- convert it to python3 using an automatic tool like [2to3](https://docs.python.org/fr/3.9/library/2to3.html)

Comment: thanks for this.  I have tried and edited my original post to reflect the additional errors I get when I try to run with python2.

Comment: @cosmarchy It's not the same problem, you should create another question for this, it seems the program you are using is not written in valid python2, where you cannot describe a function like that, which seems weird cause it seems to be an external library (maybe library is faulty, or a python3 version is installed in your python2 files for some reason)